# Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined - react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

Whenever I am importing this @react-google-maps library I am getting this error. Can anyone help me with this issue?

This is my component -

```
const {withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker} = require('react-google-maps');

const VenueMap = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        const {eventData} = this.props;
        const stateObj = {
            position: {
                lat: eventData.venue.latitude,
                lng: eventData.venue.longitude,
            },
            defaultZoom: 17
        };
        return stateObj;
    },
    render: function () {
        const {state} = this;
        const MapComponent = compose(
            withProps({
                googleMapURL: GOOGLE_MAP.mapURL,
                loadingElement: <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>,
                containerElement: <div style={{height: `300px`, marginBottom: `30px`}}/>,
                mapElement: <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>
            }),
            withScriptjs, withGoogleMap
        )(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                defaultZoom={state.defaultZoom}
                defaultCenter={state.position}>
                {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={state.position}/>}
            </GoogleMap>
        ));
        return (
            <div id="venuelocation" className="contents-wrapper">
                <div className="orgname" style={{paddingBottom: '20px'}}>Venue Location</div>
                <MapComponent isMarkerShown={true}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I am using react 16.3.2 reactjs version.

Answer (score 0):

two things.

1- it is weird for you to use React.CreateClass with React ^16 because it was removed according to this article:
[React Class being Removed](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass)

2 - I tried your code on a sandbox using the extend ES6 functionality and it works for me, actually I had to hardcode some stuff but everything is loading, although I don't have keys to open the maps api, check it out here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rjrzvlw36o

My guesses: I think you are missing a super() in some place, next time it will be helpful to also add the stack of the error, so we can see if something in particular is throwing the error.